# Python 2.7.2. How to append specific lines from multiple files into one file.

Tags: python, append, lines

I'm trying to collect specific lines from multiple text (nmap) documents and then create a new file with them all in a table format. I haven't gotten to the table part yet because I can't get the append to work.

```
#imports
import os

#Change directories
os.chdir ("M:\\Daily Testing")

#User Input
print "What is the name of the system being scanned?"
sys = raw_input("> ")

#Subfolder selected
os.chdir (sys)
os.chdir ("RESULTS")

#variables
tag = ["/tcp", "/udp"]
fout = [sys + " Weekly Summary.csv"]

import glob
for filename in glob.glob("*.nmap"):
    with open(filename, "rU") as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():
                continue
            for t in tag:
                if t in line:
                    fout.write(line)
                else:
                   continue
```

Comment: please be more specific. what error are you getting?

Comment: something seems off with `fout` being a list and then calling `fout.write()`.

Comment: The error I'm getting (currently) is "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'" on the fout.write line

Comment: fout is a list, it does not have a write function or attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have neglected to open a file to append to (`fout` is a list, not a file object, therefore it has no `.write()` method).

Change the line

```
fout = [sys + " Weekly Summary.csv"]
```

to

```
with open(sys+" Weekly Summary.csv", "w") as fout:
```

and indent the following lines accordingly.

So, something like this:

```
<snip>
import glob
with open(sys + " Weekly Summary.csv", "w") as fout:
    for filename in glob.glob("*.nmap"):
        with open(filename, "rU") as f:
            for line in f:
                if not line.strip():
                    continue
                for t in tag:
                    if t in line:
                        fout.write(line)
                    else:
                       continue
```